# How can I infinitely loop an iterator in Python, via a generator or other?

Tags: python, loops, generator

It's my understanding that using a Generator is the best way to achieve something like this, but I'm open to suggestions.

Specifically, one use case is this: I'd like to print some items alongside another list, of an arbitrary length, truncating the initial iterator as necessary.

Here is working python code that demonstrates the exact example behavior I desire:

```
    def loop_list(iterable):
        """
        Return a Generator that will infinitely repeat the given iterable.

        >>> l = loop_list(['sam', 'max'])
        >>> for i in range(1, 11):
        ...     print i, l.next()
        ... 
        1 sam
        2 max
        3 sam
        4 max
        5 sam
        6 max
        7 sam
        8 max
        9 sam
        10 max

        >>> l = loop_list(['sam', 'max'])
        >>> for i in range(1, 2):
        ...     print i, l.next()
        ... 
        1 sam
        """
        iterable = tuple(iterable)
        l = len(iterable)
        num = 0
        while num < l:
            yield iterable[num]
            num += 1
            if num >= l:
                num = 0
```

### The Problem / My Question

As you may have noticed, this only works on lists/tuples/iterables that implement `__getitem__` (if I'm not mistaken). Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass any iterable, and receive a generator that can properly loop over it's content.

If there's a better way to do something like this **without** a generator, I'm fine with that as well.

Comment: Neither of those examples represent an infinite loop, I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: The outer loop is not infinite, but the generator will continue to list its items indefinitely.

Comment: Then go with Hans' response, however as an exercise, I would suggest you consider how to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm curious about the "Equivalent to" code and related Note about memory consumption. The way I'm reading it, would `saved` continue to grow as long as the generator is accessed/`.next()` is called? **UPDATE**: Testing says no, so obviously I'm not good at reading generator code. =/ Have some learnin' to do.

Comment: No. In the source provided in the documentation, `saved` is built once (on the first time through the iterable) and then only read from then on.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) (source included on linked page).

```
import itertools

a = [1, 2, 3]

for element in itertools.cycle(a):
    print element

# -> 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 ...
```

Comment: `Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on the length of the iterable).`

Answer (score 13):

Try this-

```
L = [10,20,30,40]

def gentr_fn(alist):
    while 1:
        for j in alist:
            yield j

a = gentr_fn(L)
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()

>>gentr_fn(x,y)
10 20 30 40 10 20 30 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use module to keep it simple.
Just make sure not to start iterating from 0.

```
my_list = ['sam', 'max']

for i in range(1, 100):
    print(my_list[(i % len(my_list))-1])
```

Comment: You can start the range at `0`, easily, by simply using `for i in range(0, 100): print(my_list[i % len(my_list)])` but in any case this will only iterate 100 times, the op wants to keep cycling indeterminately.

Answer (score -7):

You can iterate over a list, appending an item to it:

```
somelist = [item1, item2, item3]
for item in somelist:
    somelist.append(item)
    do_something()
```

Comment: This will create a humongous list as your loop continues, a bad idea.