# How can I infinitely iterate through a list while specifying the starting index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration

I have a list called all_urls. I am trying to infinitely iterate through the list. I have an index i which I want to start from. For example :

> www.google.com
>
> www.facebook.com
>
> www.linkednin.com
>
> www.yahoo.com
>
> www.microsoft.com

I want to start iteration from linkedin then go in an infinite loop.

I have tried looking at this link :

[How can I infinitely loop an iterator in Python, via a generator or other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944882/how-can-i-infinitely-loop-an-iterator-in-python-via-a-generator-or-other)

but this link doesn't specify how I can start from some middle point.

I have tried

```
    for url in itertools.cycle(all_urls[i:]):
        print "Process URL : " + url
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few options.  Perhaps the easiest option is to build a new list to cycle:

```
urls = all_urls[i:] + all_urls[:i]
for url in itertools.cycle(urls):
   print(url)
```

The second solution that I'll propose is to just consume the first `i - 1` elements of the cycle:

```
# From https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(itertools.islice(iterator, n, n), None)

urls = itertools.cycle(all_urls)
consume(urls, i - 1)
for url in urls:
    print(url)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `consume(urls, i - 1)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- Yep, I suppose it should be :-).  That's also a good thing as it'll prevent infinite loops in the case that `i` somehow ends up being `None` :-)